# Is there a way to access files that Rails has minified and compressed externally?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I know that the Rails asset pipeline will, under normal circumstances, minify and compress all JS files into one, making them smaller/obfuscated but impossible to access directly from another site. I also know that the /public folder contains files that bypass this process, and can be accessed directly by URL.

My question is, is there a way in Rails to combines these processes? Can I minify/compress a file using my Ruby on Rails gems and have it still be accessible by a static URL? I'm aware that I can place JS files in app/assets to have them go through the pipeline, but if I do that will they be accessible externally?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: rails (4.2.11.3)

Comment: Rails compiles the assets and puts them in `/public/assets` in production, so the compiled and minified files should be accessible. One thing to notice is that rails will add a fingerprint sufix to the file names to improve caching, you may need to disable that is you want to access to the files by the original names.

Comment: /public folder don't bypass the process. All public files end up in this folder. Whereas you have put them manually with their original name (favico.ico or such) or they have been minified and fingerprinted. When you refer to them through a Rails helper like `<%= image_tag "my-good-image.jpg" %>` Rails will find the fingerprinted equivalent in the public folder. 
You can precompile all your static assets locally and you will see them end up fingerprinted in the public folder.

Comment: To really answer your question, you can see the access path in production. I just checked one of my fingerprinted image in production and the path is like `my-website.com/assets/my-super-cool-image-tyhgdlijsdlfijsklethfj-whatever-here-klihkugh.jpg` (Rails 5.2) and I also placed a file named `favicon.ico` in the public folder (not public/assets) and it is accessible at `my-website.com/favicon.ico`

Comment: also from Rails 5.2 Rails will warn you if you place a non fingerprinted asset in public. There is an option to explicitly allow non fingerprinted assets in the public folder. But it is not recommanded (users who have your favicon in cache can miss your new favicon for months or more depending on the caching policy you have attached to the asset).

Comment: @arieljuod Is there a way to disable fingerprinting for some files but not others?

Comment: You can try with https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets but I haven't really used it in many years

Comment: github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets works, thanks!